# Subtracting Date time value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, viewmodel

I have the upload date for a course saved in a ViewModel variable **@Model.Course.UploadDate** when calling the following code:

```
alert('@Model.Course.UploadDate');
```

I get an output as expected of:

```
21/01/2014 16:16:13
```

I know want to check that the uploadDate is within the last 10 seconds before sending a statement to the database but trying to use the following code:

```
var uploadDate = new Date('@Model.Course.UploadDate.ToLongDateString()');
alert("UPLOAD DATE " + uploadDate);
```

I get an unexpected output of:

```
Tue Jan 21 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000
```

This is the format that I need the date in only with the saved time data shown. I am then looking to perform a calculation as follows:

```
var TENSECONDS = 10 * 1000;
var uploadDate = new Date('@Model.Course.UploadDate.ToLongDateString()');
var today = new Date();
var check = today - uploadDate;

if (parseInt(check) > parseInt(TENSECONDS))
        alert("ROUTE1");
    else
        alert("ROUTE2");
```

Comment: I'm not hot on asp.net but I'd imagine there would be a dateformat function something like `dateformat(Model.Course.UploadDate.ToLongDateString(),'%mm/%dd/%yyyy %hh:%MM:%ss')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the [`documentation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) of the Date object constructor:

> value: Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1
>   January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch).

So actually that's the safest thing to pass to the constructor of a Date object instead of some strings which might be incorrectly interpreted and are completely culture dependent.

So just convert your DateTime instance to the number of milliseconds that elapsed since 1 January 1970 and feed this timestamp to the constructor:

```
var timestamp = @(Model.Course.UploadDate - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
var uploadDate = new Date(timestamp);
```

As an alternative you could use the ISO8601 format if you intend to be passing a string:

> dateString: String value representing a date. The string should be in
>   a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC
>   2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

So:

```
var uploadDate = new Date('@Model.Course.UploadDate.ToString("o")');
```

Comment: perfect Darin thats what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the following code:

```
var dateArray = new Array();
dateArray = '@Model.Course.UploadDate'.split("/");
var dateD = dateArray[0];
var dateM = dateArray[1];
var dateY = dateArray[2];
var dateT = dateArray[3];
timeArray = dateT.split(":");
var timeH = timeArray[0];
var timeM = timeArray[1];
var timeS = timeArray[2];
var dateUS = dateM + "/" + dateD + "/" + dateY + dateT;
var uploadDate = new Date(dateD,dateM,dateY,timeH,timeM,timeS);
```